# Comparative and Superlative adjectives

Tags: adjectives, comparatives

I was taught that more beautiful is a comparative adjective.  But when I think about it, wouldn't more be an adverb and beautiful be an adjective?

Comment: Yes, both are true. Compare _more beautiful_ to the adjective _prettier_.

Comment: So would you say more is an adverb?

Comment: Absolutely true. Together with an adjective, more makes a comparative adjective phrase. We use it for longer words or any that don't sound nice when adding 'er' to the end: Hotter, nicer, lovelier, more righteous, more stupid, more evocative.

Comment: More and most are adverbs when they are used to create comparative and superlative adjectives respectively. More beautiful is the comparative adjectival form of beautiful created with the help of more, the adverb.

Comment: Not quite: "more beautiful" is an adjective phrase headed by the adjective "beautiful" with the comparative adverb "more" as modifier.

Comment: And since _more ... than_ is part of the comparative construction (and only occurs there), _more_ is not so much an intensifying adverb as an auxiliary, particle, or complementizer, like the words marking other constructions.

Comment: However it is used, it is still an AdjP comprising adverb+adjective.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest analysis is that, yes, **more** is functioning as an adverb in modifying the adjective **beautiful**:

> **[more](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/more)**
>   ADVERB
>
> Forming the comparative of adjectives and adverbs, especially those of more than one syllable.
>
> Example: *‘for them enthusiasm is more important than talent’*

Regarding how to describe the two words together, BillJ [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380438/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives/380733#comment895236_380438) that "*more beautiful* is an adjective phrase headed by the adjective "beautiful" with the comparative adverb "more" as modifier."

However, in his [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380438/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives/380733#comment895294_380438) John Lawler notes that "since *more … than* is part of the comparative construction (and only occurs there), *more* is not so much an intensifying adverb as an **auxiliary, particle, or complementizer**, like the words marking other constructions" [bold emphasis is mine].